# Getting an Instance Method to return a string

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsstring

This should be simple but I'm clearly doing something painfully wrong. I want to write a test method that returns a string.

In my classTest.h I have

```
 @interface classTest : NSObject

 - (NSString *)returnTestString; 

 @end
```

classTest.m

```
- (NSString *)returnTestString; {
    NSString *currentTestString = @"123.456";
    return currentTestString;
}
```

and in the calling `module.m` I have `#import "classTest.h"` and then to call the module if I add `[classTest returnTestString]`;

I get

> "No known class method for selector 'callTestString'"

Can some point out the bleedin' obvious? - thanks EH

Comment: And the reason is that `-` signifies instance methods. If you want a class method, use `+` instead.

Comment: Well, the method above is named "returnTestString", not "callTestString".

Comment: Your code is horribly formatted. The actual problem is the ; after returnTestString in your implementation file (.m)

Comment: Many thanks, I had tried this with a + but got a different compiler error - apologies for the final bit of layout - looked OK before I submitted it.

Comment: @Taum: Actually that semicolon is not against the language. Try it. It is allowed to have a semicolon there.

Comment: Btw class names should begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @interface ClassTest : NSObject // classes always begin w/capital letters.

 - (NSString *)returnTestString; 

 @end
```

You want to call that?

```
 ClassTest *ct = [[ClassTest alloc] init];
 [ct returnTestString];
```